# Sql connection error in winforms? Window Application?

Tags: winforms

In Microsoft Window application, i write connection code in app.config file, when i am accessing in winforms it is giving error please can you help me.

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mycon"]);

     cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_Insert_Students", con );
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
     con.Open();

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stname", txtStname.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", txtClass.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", txtSection.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@states", cmdStates.SelectedText.ToString());
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: i am getting connection is not initialized

Comment: Error is : The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: when i debug, it is showing the message is :Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

Comment: Add a copy of your connection string here.

Comment: <connectionStrings >
  <add name ="mycon"  connectionString ="server=***;user id =**;password=8888;database=mydbs;"/>
   
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: Try opening the connection before you use it to create the command.

Comment: yeah me to just now observer thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's your error: the `mycon` is defined inside `<connectionStrings>` - but you're trying to load it from `.AppSettings`!

That'll never work...

You need to use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString` instead.

Try this code:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString;

     using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.USP_Insert_Students", con))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stname", txtStname.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", txtClass.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", txtSection.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@states", cmdStates.SelectedText.ToString());

         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();        
     }
}
```

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: that's what the `using()....` will automatically do for me! No need for a `try...finally` - `using()` does this already.

Comment: You're right again, I keep forgetting, too used to the DAaB ugh lol

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: <big grin> :-) time to upgrade to more modern tools !

Comment: lol Well I have to use it because of hitting Oracle and SQL both, the DAaB uses the same syntax no matter the db, all I have to do is switch out which connection string it's using from the config

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: Entity Framework v4 would do that, too - "hide" most of the differences behind LINQ and C# (or VB.NET) code

Comment: I know :-( not allowed to use that. Our DALs are all generated by DBA team, all I do is call into that layer to the method name passing in/receiving DTOs. Financial industry is very set in their ways :-)